# Using yeoman with triggerio

Tags: trigger.io, yeoman

I am trying to use trigger.io together with yeoman.
I use yeoman for the whole build cycle (scaffolding angularjs application / testing /..)
and trigger.io for the deployment. 
Trigger.io generates all in 'src' and yeoman all in 'app' directory.

Is there anyway to make Trigger.io write to an 'app' and not to a 'src' directory?

*Edit* this seems to work but not very feasible since it requires keeping track of new directories / files generated by yeoman:

- ln -s app/index.html index.html
- ln -s  app/styles styles
- ln -s  app/scripts scripts
- : continue for anything relevant

Answer (score 2):

I ended up symlinking `dist` to `src` because we needed Yeoman to compile out SCSS and CoffeScript files. The bummer here is `yeoman server` cannot be running when you `yeoman build` to create the `dist` directory. Additionally *bummerish* is when you `yeoman server` again, it cleans up the `dist` directory.

I plan on working on creating a yeoman generator for generator for Trigger and also add some grunt tasks that mimic the `Rakefile` tasks I created when we were testing and developing with Sinatra (e.g. `yeoman simulator`, `yeoman device`, `yeoman testflight`).

**edit**: I've added a few tasks directly to my `gruntfile.js` for now. I added `grunt-contrib-copy` and added the following subtasks.

```
copy: {
  app: {
    files: {
      "src/": "app/**",                 // core app files
    },
  },
  compass: {
    files: {
      "src/styles/": "temp/styles/**",  // drop in the compiled coffeescript
    }
  },
  coffee: {
    files: {
      "src/scripts/": "temp/scripts/**" // drop in the compiled scss
    }
  }
},
```

I added those tasks to the appropriate watch commands and added a new watch to watch the `app` dir.

```
watch: {
  coffee: {
    files: 'app/scripts/**/*.coffee',
    tasks: 'coffee copy:coffee reload'
  },
  compass: {
    files: [
      'app/styles/**/*.{scss,sass}'
    ],
    tasks: 'compass copy:compass reload'
  },
  app: {
    files: [
      'app/**/*.{html,png,json,css,js}'
    ],
    tasks: 'copy:app'
  },
}
```

Now `yeoman server`, which invokes `yeoman watch`, keeps `src` up to date.

I also brought in `grunt-shell` to do the following.

```
shell: {
  forge_build: {
      command: 'forge build ios 2>&1 | tee output',
      stdout: true
  },
  forge_run_device: {
      command: 'forge run ios --ios.device device',
      stdout: true
  },
  forge_run: {
      command: 'forge run ios',
      stdout: true
  }
}
```

And create some tasks like:

```
grunt.registerTask("sim", 'copy shell:forge_build shell:forge_run');
grunt.registerTask("device", 'copy shell:forge_build shell:forge_run_device');
```

I'm not entirely happy with it, but it lets me keep running `yeoman server` and drop to a console elsewhere and run `yeoman device` to bring it up in the device. it also keeps the `src` directory in a place where it can be checked in.

Eventually I'll move this to a yeoman plug in and add some more specific build tasks to clean up the src dir for the appropriate target (e.g. iOS, Android) to keep dir size small.

**edit:** I've created `grunt-forge` to help run `forge` from inside Yeoman. I've also blogged a bit about creating [a more terse output for `forge](http://fooberry.com/2013/02/12/terse-triggerio-logging/).